# Unable to read value with RegistrySearch

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

My installer need to distinguish between Intel and AMD processor manifacturer, in order to drop the corresponding components (Drivers). I've seen that is possible to catch such information from a registry key. I've done the following

```
<Property Id="REGMANIFACTURER">
  <RegistrySearch Id="RegCPU"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\ControlProcessor\0"
                  Name="VendorIdentifier"
                  Type="raw"
                  Win64="yes"
                  >
  </RegistrySearch>
```

And after drop in such way (this is the AMD case for example)

```
<ComponentGroup Id="Xxxxxx" Directory="Yyyy">
      <!--Catalog-->
      <Component Id="xxx.cat" Guid="7d79a20a-2742-4d38-be85-35a60ac512f1" Win64="yes" >
        <Condition>
          <![CDATA[Installed OR (REGMANIFACTURER <> "GenuineIntel")]]>
        </Condition>
        <File Id="xxx.cat" Source="xxx\yyy\xxx.cat" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
      </Component>
```

From MSI install logs I can see an Error 1402 (Could not open key), could you please let me know where the error is, and/or how to achieve the goal?

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Rather than trawl the registry it's often better to use the appropriate API.  GetSystemInfo() or GetNativeSystemInfo() will tell you Intel vs AMD in the processor architecture result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your Key attribute: It should be

HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\**CentralProcessor**\0

Comment: Thanks worked! In the meantime found another way, which involves in using the env. var. PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER